# Is Frege and Russell's definition of number reducible to Hilbert's?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

This is my first post on this site and I hope that its length/format is not inconsistent with any moderation guidelines. My question relates to the distinction that can be drawn between the logicist concept of number appearing in the works of Frege and Russell, and that which appears in David Hilbert’s famous 1925 address “On the Infinite.” I have no formal training in philosophy or mathematics, and would be very appreciative if anyone here could kindly comment on whether there is anything erroneous in my comprehension of the topic at hand. As far as I understand the logicist point of view, the first three positive integers can be given by the formulae:

#tFt = 1 ↔ ∃x(Fx ⋀ ∀w(Fw → w = x))
#tFt = 2 ↔ ∃x∃y(Fx ⋀ Fy ⋀ ¬(x = y) ⋀ ∀w(Fw → (w = x ∨ w = y)))
#tFt = 3 ↔ ∃x∃y∃z(Fx ⋀ Fy ⋀ Fz ⋀ ¬(x = y) ⋀ ¬(y = z) ⋀ ¬(x = z) ⋀ ∀w(Fw → (w = x ∨ w = y ∨ w = z))).

I am omitting from consideration the additional detail that the number n is in fact defined as the class of all concepts F such that #tFt = n, since this definition ultimately relies on what is written above. Next, Hilbert’s view is that finite numbers are objects of pure intuition, and are immediately recognizable as, say, strokes on a piece of paper. Hence the first three positive integers are grasped more or less intuitively by their representation in the series

|, | |, | | |.

My question is this: doesn’t the logicist definition of 1, 2, 3, … as I have written it effectively make an appeal to the same intuition that underlies the representation by “Hilbert strokes?” That is, rather than adding the symbol ‘|’ to each successive element in the series, the logicists add a new variable ‘x’ or whatever that is bound by the existential quantifier ∃. So in this sense, isn’t Hilbert’s concept of number simpler than Frege’s, since the latter cannot be made intelligible without prior acceptance of the former?

And if I may ask a second, related question - it seems that the core argument in Bertrand Russell’s “Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy” is that “all pure mathematics, insofar as it is deducible from the theory of the natural numbers, is only a prolongation of logic.” He dispenses with the primitive notions “zero”, “number”, and “successor” that underlie the Dedekind-Peano axioms, writing that “we shall have to define what we mean by adding 1” - a task that he characterizes as “by no means easy.” Treating instead as primitive the logical notion of “class," he defines “zero” as the “null class” and “successor of the number of terms in the class ⍺’’ as “the number of terms in the class consisting of ⍺ together with x, where x is any term not belonging to the class.” How does this definition avoid in any meaningful sense making an appeal to the intuitive notion of “adding 1?” I get the point that Russell saw a need to clarify the concept of number because he considered as problematic the fact that different interpretations of “zero,” “number,” and “successor” yield nonstandard models of Peano arithmetic, but doesn’t Hilbert’s more simplified treatment also manage to overcome this difficulty by merely asserting that there is no ambiguity in the meaning of “zero” and “add one” in a mathematical context, and hence there is good reason to treat these notions as primitive?

Comment: The issue regarding the "definition" of numbers is thorny; in a nutshell, Hilbert starts from an *intuition* about symbols and thus finite numbers are symbols. Frege and Russell define the concept of *number* in purely logical terms: a number is a concept applying to concepts.

Comment: In both cases, we have to rely on a fundamental capabilities to "perceive" different objects: different particulars being terms of the same class (Russell) or different tokens of the same type (Hilbert's strokes).

Comment: Frege's logicism of numbers was based on his famous [Hume's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hume%27s_principle): *HP plays a central role in Gottlob Frege's philosophy of mathematics. Frege shows that HP and suitable definitions of arithmetical notions entail all axioms of what we now call second-order arithmetic. This result is known as Frege's theorem, which is the foundation for a philosophy of mathematics known as neo-logicism. HP had been used to great effect by Cantor whose writings Frege knew*. Hilbert's intuitive semiotic definition above lacks or doesn't embody/emphasize HP.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Many thanks for your reply. Providing a "definition" of numbers is indeed a tricky endeavour, and my question arose from an initial impression that Bertrand Russell's treatment of this topic seems to obscure rather than elucidate the foundations of number theory. I think that most mathematicians see it as immediately obvious that "zero" is 0, "one" is 1, "two" is 1 + 1, and so on. Hence no further clarification and/or definitions are required.

Comment: Russell's purpose (and Frege's) was not to "elucidate" number theory, but to show that it is reducible to resources of logic alone. They did not care how complex the reduction might be, only that it is possible in principle. Hilbert had a completely different foundational program that presupposed intuitions of symbol manipulation, something logicists find unacceptable. So their definitions can be "equivalent" only in some Pickwickian sense that both would reject. For broader perspective you may want to look at [Frege-Hilbert correpondence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-hilbert/).

Comment: @DoubleKnot Thank you for your reply. Insofar as Hilbert's (and Cantor's) work on this subject stemmed from that of Dedekind who considered the notion of a function/mapping/correspondence to be intuitively obvious and hence primitive/irreducible, could it not be seen to embody Hume's principle as well? In any event, your comments provide some helpful ideas about what else I should be reading going forward to enhance my understanding of the topic.

Comment: Agreed. From a mathematical point of view the "natural" intuition about the number sequence is enough, but philosophers search for (hope for) a deeper understanding.

Comment: The difference is IMO: a philosopher doing mathematics (Russell) and a mathematician doing philosophy (Hilbert).

Comment: Indeed as a human it's also possible to treat above Hilbert strokes as the ostensive *equivalence classes* modulo bijection thus it's also follows HP, but since the strokes are so simple maybe an alien with totally different visual system as ours won't understand this level of deep principles such as Hume-Cantor's. A logicist exemplified by Frege is keen on the content of any propositional thought down to its deepest possible conceptual analysis besides inference rules and other syntax. So expressed in FOL with much more details, above said aliens may glean more HP info from above pattern...

Comment: Re your "I get the point that Russell saw a need to clarify the concept of number because he considered as problematic the fact that different interpretations of “zero,” “number,” and “successor” yield nonstandard models of PA", Russell didn't envision any incompleteness when published said book in 1919, nor did Hilbert. For a logicist as Frege disagreeing with Hilbert's model theoretic approach to logic it doesn't make sense to have any nonstandard model since for them a theory is fixed to 1 interpretation and logic is all there is. While for Hilbert one needs metaphysic layer to apply logic.

Comment: @DoubleKnot Thank you for the additional feedback. Perhaps I shouldn't have used the word "model" in my reference to Russell's point of view since it doesn't technically appear in his book. That is nonetheless my interpretation of what he is saying in the first chapter - he is seeking a logical foundation of mathematics, and he views the axioms of Dedekind-Peano arithmetic as unsuitable because different interpretations of "zero" and "successor" yield different definitions (i.e., models) of the natural numbers. Hence his perceived need to clarify what "zero" and "successor" really mean.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for this helpful clarification. I suppose that the elucidation that I was referring to was definitional, rather than something providing any new insight into the mathematical theory of the positive integers (which is probably why modern mathematicians' interest in this particular work is limited). Regarding your point about logicism and intuitions about symbol manipulation, this directly addresses the question that appears in the title of my post. Without presupposition of these intuitions, aren't the "logical" definitions of #tFt = n as Frege writes them unintelligible?

Comment: Frege did not much care about intelligibility or symbols either. To him logical and mathematical ideas inhabit objective realm, and would inhabit it without any humans to intuit them, notate them in symbols or manipulate the symbols. His only concern was whether, in their pristine detached abstraction, the latter are just the former in disguise too complex for humans to immediately see through. For the purpose of seeing it they are, of course, welcome to symbols, intuitions or whatever other crutches their humble minds require, but none of that has anything to do with the ideas themselves.

Comment: @Conifold Fascinating! Thank you very much for this insightful feedback.